# How to write data into DBF using Pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho

How to write data into DBF using Hitachi Pentaho(ETL TOOL),i can't find the right way.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JDBC driver to read/write data to DBF files. Adding that driver to the Pentaho Data Integration installation, you could use the Table Output step with a **Generic database** Connection type/Dialect configured to use that driver.

Read Pentaho Data Integration documentation to learn the directory where you need to add the JDBC driver. Then you'll need to read the driver documentation to learn how to use it to manipulate DBF files, I haven't work with DBF, but to use the Generic database connection type to connect to SQLite databases (instead of the SQLite specific Connection type/Dialect) I configure the **Custom connection URL** with this value: `jdbc:sqlite:/path_to_my_db/MyDBfile.sqlite` and the **Custom driver class name** with the value `org.sqlite.JDBC`. I don't need user/password to connect with this database. DBF JDBC Driver will use something similar, I suppose.